# Batch operation isn't called

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I have a module with batch operations, this is my hook_menu

```
$items['some-pretty-url'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Title',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('import_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

...and this is my batch config

```
$batch  = array(
    'title'            => t('Lorem ipsum Elit pariatur Duis et elit aute.'),
    'init_message'     => t('Commencing...'),
    'operations'       => $operations,
    'progress_message' => t('Processed: @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message'    => t('An error occurred during processing.'),
    'finished'         => '_import_finished',
);
```

Batch works pretty good if I have the module definition in the .module file, but if I move the functions to another file the batch simply does not work at all.

```
$items['some-pretty-url'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Title',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('import_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file'             => 'module_definition.inc', //move module to another file
);

$batch  = array(
    'title'            => t('Lorem ipsum Elit pariatur Duis et elit aute.'),
    'init_message'     => t('Commencing...'),
    'operations'       => $operations,
    'progress_message' => t('Processed: @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message'    => t('An error occurred during processing.'),
    'finished'         => '_import_finished',
    'file'             => 'module_definition.inc', //batch functions are here
);
```

Batch function is not being called even if I set the file argument in the batch configuration.

Comment: Have you checked by clearing cache?

Comment: 3 times, @Clive has a very usefull answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a batch the URL automatically changes to /batch...at that path, Drupal doesn't know to include your module_definition.inc file. It'll only process the menu hook when the path is 'some-pretty-url', so module_definition.inc will only be included then.

If you move your batch *definition* into the module file it'll start working, and the `file` you've told the batch system to find the processing function in will be included as you'd expect, because now Drupal knows it needs to be included.

Comment: yeah, I have everything in the module file, I just wanted to create a different file for the logic, really usefull answer !